# Currency formatting Canadian French with custom filter

Tags: angularjs

I am using a custom filter that utilizes angular's basic currency filter to display a monetary value based on a locale setting of en_CA or fr_CA. The display will either look like $123,456,789.99 or 123.456.789,99$ respectively. My question comes down to how do I make the angular currency filter handle formatting the value or must I do string replacements?

Filter code:

```
  angular.module('plunker').filter('customCurrency',
    [ '$filter', function(filter) {
      var currencyFilter = filter('currency');
      return function(languageCode,amount, currencySymbol) {
        if(languageCode=='en_CA'){
           currencySymbol='$';
        }else if(languageCode=='fr_CA'){
          currencySymbol='';
        }
        return currencyFilter(amount, currencySymbol);
      }
    } ]);
```

The plunker is located at http://plnkr.co/edit/7JJhd6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just went with the string replacement. The plunker from the original question contains the working example that I ended up using.